# Selecting multiple files in a dart based chrome app

Tags: api, google-chrome, filesystems, dart, google-chrome-app

I was playing around with Google Dart and chrome apps. I tried to select a single file: No problem here!

The code looks like this and prints the filename.

```dart
Future<ChooseEntryResult> res = chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(new ChooseEntryOptions());
res.then((ChooseEntryResult entry) {
  print("entries: " + entry.entry.name);
});
```

But selecting multiple files does not work. In a native chrome app I can do:

```dart
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({"acceptsMultiple":true}, function(entries) {
  console.log(entries);
});
```

Even this code fails (I only added acceptsMultiple: false)

```dart
Future<ChooseEntryResult> res = chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(new ChooseEntryOptions(acceptsMultiple: false));  
res.then((ChooseEntryResult entry) {
  print("entries: " + entry.entry.name);
});
```

I would expect this to work:

```dart
Future<ChooseEntryResult> res = chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(new ChooseEntryOptions(acceptsMultiple: true));  
res.then((ChooseEntryResult entry) {
  print("entries: " + entry.entries);
});
```

But whenever I select multiple files the "entry" and "entries" fields of ChooseEntryResult gives me null. Has anyone managed to get this working?

Comment: The use of acceptsMultiple seems bugged in both ways, i added an issue few days ago: http://goo.gl/Re3ymF

Comment: Ok cool. But it's 30 days ago and no reply yet?

Comment: Yep, i m maybe wrong, but i think it's not really "hard maintained" because dart-gde is generating the library from IDLs.

Comment: Oh ok - I'll try to fix it myself then. Or Write my own wrapper/lib